# Not able to connect to Redshift due to IP Restrictions

Tags: powerbi, amazon-redshift, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to connect to redshift through Power BI service, however our redshift needs IPs to be whitelisted.

We have tried tracing the request hitting redshift and whitelisting that IP, however after some time we were unable to access redshift from power BI service.

Is there any way I can know the list of IP addresses which has to be whitelisted on redshift to have uninterrupted access to the data on Power BI service(premium per user)?

I have tried tracing the IPs which were hitting our redshift, whitelisting the IPs provided under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/common/outbound-ip-addresses#power-platform

Comment: try the data centre ip ranges https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Comment: Better use [Power BI Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/integrate-power-bi-with-amazon-redshift-for-insights-and-analytics/).